# Create Class Object within Method of Another Class C++

Tags: class, methods, heap-memory, delegation, stack-memory

I am new to C++. How do you create a method within one class which initializes an object within another class with specified parameters? Something like the following.

```
class A { 

public:

    double X;

    double Y;

    A(double a, double b) {

    X = a;

    Y = b;

    };

class B {

public:

 A f(double a, double b) {
    //Initialize an object of type A using parameters specified.
    };
};
```

I want to use the object of type A later so, presumably, I would need to use the new operator within f. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `f()` should return `A*`, i.e., `A* f(double a, double b) { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful. How would the body of f look? Using the dummy code above, what's analogous to what I tried is A* f(double a, double b) { B new objectB(a, b); return objectB}; However, this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class B {
 public:
  A* f(double a, double b) { return new A(a, b); };
};
```

Although you could just as easily do `new A(a,b)` anywhere you wanted to do `B.f(a,b)`.

Comment: Actually, would you happen to know how to access the variables? I've been trying B.f(a, b)->X but it doesn't work.

Comment: `B.f()` returns a new object of type `A`. You'd need to access the returned type-`A` object outside of `B`, such as `A* obj_a = B.f(v1, v2); obj_a->something_of_A();`. You probably want to review a book about object oriented programming for a start.

Comment: I do! This is pretty abstract stuff. Thanks for your help!